# Set variable in layout and access it in template

Tags: grails

I'm setting a variable in grails-app/views/layout/main.gsp to a value, like

```
<g:set var="welcometext" scope="session">Hello, pleased to meet you!</g:set>
```

But when I try to access it in my view grails/app/views/index.gsp with

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="layout" content="main"/>  
</head>

${welcometext}

<body>
</html>
```

Nothing gets printed out. So the variable set in main.gsp is not accessible to my view index.gsp. I tried also to set the scope to page, request and session, but success.

How can I set a variable in my layout main.gsp and reference it in other views?

Comment: There is really no good reason to do that.  The site mesh layout is not a good place to do that sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define variables in your page (*index*) and your layout can see them (which is really useful for breadcrumb for example). 
However, you can't access to a variable defined in your layout from your page (*index*) because the page is rendered like there was no layout, and then we apply the layout to the page rendered.

As a shortcut, you can see the rendering flow like this: *(render Index)* THEN *(render Layout)*

So, in your case, you have to find another solution, depending on your content:

- Put the welcometext in session (not the best solution)
- Pass it as a parameter of each view (not the best solution)
- Create a custom [tag](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.1/guide/single.html#taglibs) to automatically print it
- Create a template and render it where you need
- Hardcode it ? (I don't like this one, but it's closer to what you're trying to do)
- Use JavaScript to add the text ?
- ...

Try to see which one is the best for you ;)